# jquery animation repeated several times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the animation. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
        <title>title</title>
        <style>
            div{
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: green;
                position:relative;
                left: 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Animation</h1>
        <select id='text_1' type="text">
            <option>100</option>
            <option>200</option>
            <option>300</option>
            <option>400</option>
            <option>500</option>
            <option>600</option>
            <option>700</option>
            <option>800</option>
            <option>900</option>
            <option>1000</option>
        </select>
        <button>Animate Div</button><br/><br/>
        <div></div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var number = 500;
                $('#text_1').bind('change', function(){
                    var number_2 = $('#text_1').val() != '' ? $('#text_1').val() : 500;
                    animation(number_2);
                });
                animation(number);
            });
            function animation(num){
                $('button').click(function(){
                    $('div').animate({
                        'left': num+'px',
                    }, 1000).animate({
                        'left': '0px',
                    }, 1000);;
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I change select option (example: 300) and click the button, then does a two animations.
when I change select option again, then does a tree animations.
What is wrong. Please help.

Comment: animation this function is called two times inside change event and on button click event..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant solution, but if you modify your code to look like this:

```
function animation(num) {
    $('button').unbind('click'); //this removes the old click event
    $('button').click(function(){
        ....
    }
}
```

then that should solve your problem.

Comment: @user1920428 does drop down change event is really needed..?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove events.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('button').on('click',function()
    {
        var num = $('#text_1').val() != '' ? $('#text_1').val() : 500;

        $('div').animate(
        {
            'left': num+'px',
        }, 1000).animate(
        {
            'left': '0px',
        }, 1000);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not matter for this, but you should learn how to use a Javascript debugger, like Firebug, if that might give you a clue.

If you used a debugger, and you set a breakpoint inside the "click" function, you'd see it getting hit multiple times, adding up to the number of times you've changed the option dropdown.  I'm guessing that's because your "animation()" function is binding a NEW function to the "click" event every time it's called, and not removing the previous ones, so clicking the button will execute the "click" function multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you probably meant

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var number = 500;
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('div').stop().animate({
            'left': number+'px',
        }, 1000).animate({
            'left': '0px',
        }, 1000);
    });
    $('#text_1').bind('change', function(){
        number = $('#text_1').val() != '' ? $('#text_1').val() : 500;
    });
});
```

otherwise you are binding the click event to the button every single time you animate which becomes the problem. The first time the click is binded once, so it animates once, then you animation binds to click again, so it animates twice. Also notice the stop() which causes the div to stop what it is doing and start a new animation to prevent stuff where you click the button multiple times and it keeps animating for several seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You're binding the click event multiple times.

Change it to this:

```
            $('button').off('click').on('click', function(){
                $('div').animate({
                    'left': num+'px',
                }, 1000).animate({
                    'left': '0px',
                }, 1000);;
            });
```

Keep in mind `.off` and `.on` replaced `.bind` and `.unbind`
Also, it's better for performance reasons to chain functions like this.